# How to run more than two UST-10LX or UST-20LX in ROS using urg node?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble in running two UST-10LX in same laptop since it uses an Ethernet interface.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203526/how-to-run-more-than-two-ust-10lx-or-ust-20lx-in-ros-using-urg-node?/) by [ums_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21686/ums_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will have to change the IP settings of one of your UST. After that use a router to connect Lidars with your PC. Then change IPV4 settings to manual and IP address to 192.168.0.100 (as told by hokuyo). After all this you will be able to run both the lidars individually using the command `rosrun urg_node urg_node _ip_address:="192.168.0.10"` for the lidar with default settings and `_ip_address:="192.168.0.x"` for new settings.

For launching both these together you can make a launch file. You can use:

```
<launch>
  <node ns="lidar1" pkg="urg_node" type="urg_node" name="lidar1" >
    <param name="ip_address" value="192.168.0.10"/>
  </node>
  <node ns="lidar2" pkg="urg_node" type="urg_node" name="lidar2" >
    <param name="ip_address" value="192.168.0.12"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

It will work for sure. Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [rechie26](https://answers.ros.org/users/21687/rechie26/) with karma: 38 on 2015-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fozzy-b](https://answers.ros.org/users/47896/fozzy-b/) on 2020-02-13**:
afaik this does get both running, but the default ros topic for urg_node is "scan." Doesn't this mean that one of the scans will always override the other?

**Comment by [rechie26](https://answers.ros.org/users/21687/rechie26/) on 2020-02-13**:
That's why we have different namespace arguments. It will publish topics as lidar1/scan and lidar2/scan.

**Comment by [fozzy-b](https://answers.ros.org/users/47896/fozzy-b/) on 2020-02-13**:
Goodness. I should try reading attentively.